# Getting error While installing dkpg openssh-client

Tags: dpkg

I am running below cmd

```
sudo dpkg -i openssh-client_1%3a5.3p1-3ubuntu7_i386.deb
```

And getting this error:

```
(Reading database ... 197494 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack openssh-client_1%3a5.3p1-3ubuntu7_i386.deb ...
Unpacking openssh-client (1:5.3p1-3ubuntu7) over (1:5.3p1-3ubuntu7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openssh-client:
 openssh-client depends on libssl0.9.8 (>= 0.9.8k-1).

dpkg: error processing package openssh-client (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openssh-client
```

Please Suggest

Comment: Why are you trying to install using `dpkg` (which doesn't automatically resolve dependencies) rather than `apt-get` or `apt` (which do)?

Comment: That's a pretty old `openssh-client`, what version of Ubuntu are you running.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to install a specific version of openssh server you can do this through APT you don't have to do it with dpkg.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1%3a5.3p1-3ubuntu7:i386
```

This way any dependencies (such as libssl) will be installed for you by APT.

I would check the format of the version string as it looks a bit wierd.

Comment: %3A probably represents ':'